# Creating a template in TexWorks - Refreshing the texworks database?

Tags: miktex, templates, texworks

I am using TexWorks and I want to add in my own templates. I have added a folded 'Custom Templates' to ~/user/Texworks/templates but that folder does not appear to have been recognized by Texworks. [image: folder doesn't appear]

is there a way to...refresh(?) texworks so that it reads the folder and its contents is there

Comment: On my Linux system, there's a dot in front of Texworks folder name. Maybe Windows also puts a dot there?

Comment: @RobtAll I am the OP (posted on wrong account), but adding a dot, ".Custom Templates" did not change anything unfortunately.

Comment: I meant `~/user/.Texworks/templates` with the dot just in front of Texworks. On Linux, that is a hidden folder. You cannot se it in your file manager, unless you configure the file manager to show hidden files and folders (easy to do, it's a menu option in the file manager). On Windows, the folder would not be hidden by the dot, but it might be listed in an unexpected order when you open the user folder (because the dot places it in a different alphabetical order).

Comment: @Ozera To make sure you're in the correct folder, open TeXworks and choose Scripts --> Scripting TeXworks --> Show Scripts Folder. That will open the folder, go one level up and you should find the templates folder.

Comment: @Ozera Also, you can ask to get accounts merged: https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts